# ¿Como puedo cancelar la conexión a una SQL?

Tags: java

Necesito cancelar la conexión a una SQL en cierto tiempo.

Estoy almacenando datos de usuarios en una SQL, pero aveces la conexión tarda mas de lo normal, y quiero cancelar eso.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Estoy almacenando datos de usuarios en una SQL, pero aveces tarda demasiado y quiero cancelar eso, entonces lo que quiero hacer seria que en X tiempo eso se cancele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no tengo claro el contexto de lo que buscas, esta función tiene un argumento `$sec` que define cuantos segundos puede esperar a recibir respuesta antes de cerrarse la conexión.

```
int mysqli_poll ( array &$read , array &$error , array &$reject , int $sec [, int $usec ] )
```

Este problema ya se había planteado en StackOverflow Inglés.

Fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query

Y tienes información adicional aquí:
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.poll.php

Espero que te sea útil.